# From where my Rest API is running if I ran it on embedded tomcat and the IDE is closed?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, tomcat, intellij-idea

Today I installed IntelliJ IDEA IDE and ran a REST API I built using Spring framework. I ran that on the embedded tomcat server. I  closed the IDE, still, the API is running and all the operations are live.

I am quite confused:

1. From where the API is running?
2. Why I never experienced this with Eclipse STS?
3. How do I stop the REST service now?

**Environment details**:
**OS**: macOS
**IDE**: IntelliJ IDEA
**Buid tool**: Maven

I started the app using the starter class provided in the Spring-Boot app.

```
public class WebsiteEmbeddedRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebsiteEmbeddedRunner.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Update**: I ran `px gs | grep website` which returned me the process ID. I killed the process and the REST API also stopped. I am still confused from where it was running because I started and stopped the service from IDE and it's working as expected.

I will close the question after a few hours, as I am still curious to know the reason behind it.

Comment: What is your OS? How the app is started? What build system are u using?

Comment: Please see the updated question.

Comment: Don't know how to kill a process on Mac. Also make sure that IntellJ is really not running.

Comment: I did make sure that there is no program running and then closed the IntelliJ

Comment: I killed the process and API also got stopped. Plz see update.

Comment: You can also enable this in your IntelliJ IDE **Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > On Closing Tool Window with Running Process > Terminate Process** to stop your service after closing.

Comment: IDEA starts Tomcat service where your application is running. If you don't select "Terminate" on exit, but just "disconnect" then IDE is closed, but Tomcat process still runs fine.